# Parallelize execution on 2D Array - lock single field / cells of array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, concurrency, parallel-processing, synchronized

Iam working on the parallelization of the calculation of a 2D-Array. To be more precise, iam trying to parallize the simulation of a predator-prey szenario. Therefore, i am using a 2D-Array, in which each field of the array displays a pixel. For the parallelization, iam deviding the field to the given number of threads in subfields - one for each thread. The threads should perform the calculation for each field in each sub-array simultaniously.

More information about my algorithm:

1. Step: it chooses a random cell inside its subfield (xi, yi)
2. Step: it chooses a random neighbor field --> left, right, above, below of (xi,yi), called xin, yin
3. Step: it chooses randomly, if it performe a move, selection or reproduction action

Here is an example of the move action:

```
    public void move(int xi, int yi, int xin, int yin){
       String temp = this.simulationBoard[xi][yi];
       this.simulationBoard[xi][yi] = this.simulationBoard[xin][yin];
       this.simulationBoard[xin][yin] = temp;
    }
```

Now regarding the parallelization:

- Each thread performs the algorithm on its subfield (this is ensured by only randomly choosing cells in the subfield (by specifying borders))
- The only difference is, that in Step 2 of the algorithm it is checked, wether (xi,yi) or (xin,yin) are located in a critical region
- critical region means, that 2 Threads could both perform an action on the field of the array ((xi,yi) or (xin,yin))
- critical regions are simplified the boarders of each sub-field

So my goal is to ensure, that if a threads performs an action on the element of the 2d array that is located in a critical region,
only one thread can perform the action at a time. During this, the other threads should nether read nor write the element.

My current approach is:

All threads are performing methods on the instance of the SimulationBoard class see below:

```
    public class SimulationBoard{
    
       private String[][] simulationBoard;
    
       ...
    
       public void move(int xi, int yi, int xin, int yin, boolean lockXiYi, boolean lockXinYin) {
            if(lockXiYi && lockXinYin){
                this.moveXiYiXinYinLocked(xi, yi, xin, yin);
            }
            else if(lockXiYi){
                this.moveXiYiLocked(xi, yi, xin, yin);
            }
            else if(lockXinYin){
                this.moveXinYinLocked(xi, yi, xin, yin);
            }
            else {
                this.moveUnlocked(xi, yi, xin, yin);
            }
       }
        ...
    
        // here, only one thread at a time should acces and perform actions on the element simulationBoard[xi][yi]
        public void moveXiYiLocked(int xi, int yi, int xin, int yin){
            synchronized(simulationBoard[xi][yi]){
                String temp = this.simulationBoard[xi][yi];
                this.simulationBoard[xi][yi] = this.simulationBoard[xin][yin];
                this.simulationBoard[xin][yin] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

So this is my current status..

now when i am performing my simulation on a 600 x 400 field for example with 4 threads, the whole simulation is not getting any faster. for other configuration the result is more or less the same..

Is my logic wrong or something like that?
Is synchronized(array[xi][yi]) blocking the whole array maybe???

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I think the first thing I would do is try to do this single-threaded, and optimize that solution as much as possible.  If the result is still too slow, you can try multi-threading.  However if you get the speed required, stop.

Comment: The second thing: yes your synchronization looks a little suspect.  If you have too much synchronization between threads, then likely each thread will end up waiting on the other thread, and you won't see an improvement over the single threaded implementation.  C.f. Amdahl's Law.

Comment: So some ideas: a lot of times two arrays may be used.  One is read only, it contains the data you need.  The other is used for output only, and is private to each thread.  At the end, values from each thread are merged (for example, by summing) to get the final correct value.  If you need something more complex, send output values to a single thread with a task that calculates the intersection of two sub-arrays.  It uses one lock for the entire intersection, this will reduce the number of times you need to take and release a lock, which reduces overhead.

Comment: Its a task from my university so it is mandetory to parallelize it..

Comment: Well, I think you should use fewer locks.  The current version seems guaranteed to run slowly, at least as I see it.

Comment: There’s a lot wrong but first, what type does your array have?

Comment: two dimensional string array (String[][])

Answer (score 1):

First of all, developing multi-threaded applications is a complex topic. The complexity may exceed everything you’ve learned so far, so it’s weird to get an assignment including parallel processing from your university without any guidance.

Parallel read access does not impose any problems and hence, does not require locking. On the other hand, problems can occur with concurrent access to the same data while at least one thread modifies it. This is what requires appropriate measures.

The next fundamental thing you need to understand is: *`synchronized` does not lock anything*.

When two or more threads try to execute a synchronized block or method, synchronizing *on the same object*, they have to execute the block or method one after the other. The thread entering the synchronized block or method after the other is guaranteed to see the modifications made by the other thread before leaving the synchronized block or method, consistently. But there is no restriction on which data the thread(s) may modify and nothing prevents other threads from modifying the same data without `synchronized`.

It’s up to you to arrange the code in a way that all access to the same mutable data is done within synchronized blocks or methods, synchronizing on the same object. A natural valid protocol would be to use the same object whose fields your are accessing for the synchronization, but nothing enforces this. It’s also valid to use a different object for synchronization than the one you’re modifying, you might even modify more than one object, *as long as all threads adhere to the same protocol*.

So when you use `synchronized(array[xi][yi]){ … }` you are *not* locking the array element. You are reading the array element, without synchronization as the synchronized block has not entered yet, and synchronizing on the object whose reference you read. Since you said, the objects are (immutable) `String`s, it’s clear that you are not modifying the object but assigning a new string, as that’s the only way to update a string array.

This is completely broken. Two threads performing `synchronized(array[xi][yi]){ … }` for the same `xi` and `yi` may see different objects at the array location and synchronizing on different objects is as good as having no synchronization at all. For completeness, it’s also possible to get over-synchronization when the same string is stored at different array locations, but performance problems are irrelevant as long as the program isn’t correct.

It might be overkill to create a distinct object for each (600 x 400) array location to lock on those. But how a useful solution might look like depends on how much overlapping your sub-fields actually have and how many writes are necessary in your algorithm, compared to the number of read accesses. That’s a new question, requiring more information about your actual algorithm.

Comment: Thanks! Check my edit above, i added more informations